# Windows containers 2016 run powershell as a domain user

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

I want to be able to either run a Windows Container as a domain user

Example (no idea on how to run as a different user)

```
docker run -it microsoft/nanoserver powershell
```

Or alternatively being able to run powershell script in the container as a domain user. I would have to pass in -e to docker run .. but that is ok.

The reason for this is to run something like (but the application uses domain resources like SQL and file shares)

```
dotnet app.dll
```

Comment: good question! there is a -u switch for docker run, but that seems to have no influence. inside the container the user is: `USERDOMAIN                     User Manager
USERNAME                       ContainerAdministrator` and from the host's sight the user-id is access denied....   Did you already checked the docker forums and github site for such answers and issues? Docker for Server 2016 is fully supported by docker inc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer to your question eventually found it's way to the container docs and is brand new.
please refer to this link until it will be published in the MSDN container site.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/live/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts.md

----edit:---
and live link has moved again:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts